# How arrow function expression gets executed with { }

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I ran into this case while working with find function for Arrays in Javascript.

I would like to understand how Javascript engine handled the arrow function expression when I had wrongly put curly braces **"{ }"** inside it.

```
//Array Declaration
const phones = [{ brand: "Samsung", id: 10 }, { brand: "Apple", id: 20 }];

//correct way
let phone = phones.find(phone => phone.id === 10);
console.log("Correct result: ", phone);

//wrong way
phone = phones.find(phone => {
  phone.id === 10;
});
console.log("Wrong result: ", phone);
```

Correct result:  {brand: "Samsung", id: 10}
Wrong result:  undefined

Comment: `return c.id === 10;`?

Comment: It signifies a multi-line body. You need `()` to make it into an object.

Comment: it's phone.id === 10

Comment: You can match the "correct way" by writing `{ return phone.id === 10; }` in the "wrong way".

Comment: Your function does not return anything, hence "undefined".

Comment: Got that now, Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.find()` expects a Boolean to be returned. In the first example you are implicitly returning `phone.id === 10`.

In the second example you are not using implicit return because you have used `{}`. You need to explicitly return the value using `return` keyword.

```
phone = phones.find(c => {
   return phone.id === 10;
});
```